# Something after after duals?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

So if I have a polyhedron, x. Is it possible for a shape to be inscribed inside x (y). And inside y is z, but inside z is x. Is there a shape that could be x? If so what is it?
Also, x, y, and z are different shapes.

Comment: Trying to clean up what you're asking a bit: what you want is a 'well-defined' mapping $\mathcal{P}$ from (possibly convex) polyhedra to (again, possibly convex) polyhedra such that $\mathcal{P}(p)\subset p$ for every polyhedron $p$ (considered as a solid shape), $\mathcal{P}(p)\not\cong p$, $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(p))\not\cong p$, but $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(p)))\cong p$, i.e. sort of a 'order-three' duality?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think so, if I understand you right.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can come up with sporadic examples: Start with an octahedron, whose dual is a cube.

Inside a cube, you can inscribe a tetrahedron (by choosing "every other" vertex of the cube).

Then, use the midpoint of each edge of the tetrahedron to inscribe an octahedron. (Note that the final octahedron will have a different orientation than what you started with; it isn't a scaled version of the first octahedron, as would happen with a double dual).

In general, let's say we call $d(P)$ the dual of a polyhedron $P$. Now, $d(P)$ has certain nice properties related to the dual of a vector space, giving us that $d \circ d (P) = d^2(P) = P$; we go into the dual space for the dual, and back to our space for the double dual (although our space and the dual are isomorphic, so we can stay in our space if we please).

It seems that, if we call your desired map $t$ and demand that $t^3(P) = P$, then it will be hard for $t$ to have properties that are as nice as those of $d$, as we can't use the dual space in an obvious way.

Comment: With the octahedron example I'm not quite seeing what you mean, you lose me at "choosing 'every other' vertex..." what do you mean by that, also by your standards most shapes could do this be randomly inscribing them within each other.

Comment: @tox123 I couldn't find, in what you wrote, any higher standards. I was just giving you an example that the situation you described is possible for some polyhedra. I also gave you reasons why I believe the more precise version of what we're *assuming* you want, would have to be quite unusual. Here is the situation I was describing: [link](http://science.larouchepac.com/kepler/harmony-old/BookII/pictures/cube%20octa%20tetra%20nest.jpg)

Comment: What I'm assuming you're assuming I want is what I want.